# Not getting toast in clicking an item in spinner

Tags: android, spinner

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Spinner s = new Spinner(this);

        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) 
        findViewById(R.id.activity_main);

        String ss[] = {"--Select Item--", "Item1", "Item2", "Item3", 
                       "Item4", "Item5"};

        ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                           android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, ss);

        s.setAdapter(ad);


        rl.addView(s);


        s.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                TextView t = (TextView) v;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getText().toString(), 
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
}

}
```

When i am long pressing on an item in spinner I am not  getting any Toast which  should come as the  code specifies it so above. Also, when long pressing the spinner itself (not the item in the dropdown list in the spinner) then the app is crashing. Why is that so?

Edit 1:

```
s.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TextView t = (TextView) view;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

When using setOnItemLongClickListener instead of setOnLongClickListener then when long pressing an item in dropdown list of spinner should generate a toast but it is not giving so?

Comment: Have you tried lust putting any string e.g. "Hello Toast" in the toast message and not using t.getText() and seeing if that works?

Comment: @AaronThompson Yes,tried nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `longClickListener` is set on a `Spinner` class and you are casting that view to a `TextView` inside the listener. That is why the app crashes.

`Spinner.setOnLongClickListener` is not the listener for each of the adapter items.

What you are looking for is  `Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener())`

Comment: one more doubt that when I am using setOnItemLongClickListener() thn it should give Toast when I long press on spinner item but it is not coming. I am adding that code in an edit.Please clarify that too.Thanks in advance